# Issue with android class library resources after updating xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

After updating to the newest release from xamarin I am experiencing some issues regarding resources.

We have a android class library which contains our core android app features, e.g activities, android resources(default Icons and so forth).

This is referenced by multiple android projects each containing their own android resources for example Icons. This is caused by we are selling different instances of the same app, only resource graphic is different.

When build the android application uses the Resources from the android class library and not its own Resources.

Earlier the android app woud use it owns resources so I am not sure what is different now.

We are using the same setup for ios and this works as earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the top of the Xamarin Forums, specifically in the Android section, you will [find a post mentioning a plethora of breaking changes and known issues](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37277/stable-release-xamarin-android-5-1-0-breaking-changes-new-features-and-bug-fixes/p1). This is also described in [the release notes](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/).

The workaround right now is to avoid having the same resource names both in the library and the application. See [Xamarin Bugzilla 29326](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29326).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response - I am looking at the bug report right now, but I am not sure I understand the workaround. - Workaround at this point would be to avoid using the same string key that is used in the Nuget packages. In this case that key is "ApplicationName" -

Comment: What is it you do not understand?

Comment: In my android class library I use a android resource named logo.png this is added to a nuget package  <file src="..\MissionsApp.App.Droid\Resources\drawable-hdpi\logo.png" target="content\MonoAndroid\Resources\drawable-hdpi\logo.png" /> If a specific logo is needed in the app a new logo.png is added to the drawables in the android project. How can I use different names for logo in the library and in the application? Is I name it otherwise the logo.png will not be found

Comment: This does not answer my question about what you do not understand.

Comment: That is exactly what does not work right now! So you can't do that. The workaround is not to use the same names in both the nuget and the application. So you have to handle that.

Comment: Okay I get it, that sucks, Not sure "how to handle that" but I will find a solution. Tak skal du have